# Linear models when responses have no link

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear-model, intuition

I am studying normal linear regression and wanted to ask a question about its utility when working with independent RV. Suppose that we have for $k \in [1,\dots,n]$, $$Y_k = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{k1} + \beta_2x_{k2} + \dots + \beta_qx_{kq} + \epsilon_k \quad \text{where } \epsilon_k \sim_{ind} N(0,\sigma^2)$$

We can write put all $Y_k$ in a vector $Y$, put the explanatory variables in a matrix $X$ and parameters in a vector $\beta$ and write $Y=X\beta +  \epsilon $ where the disturbance vector $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2 Id)$.

However, in real life thinking, I do not see an utility to this matrix form if we are studying things that have no link. If $Y_1$ is the points you receive when asking a question in this website, $Y_2$ the salary of employees in a company, $Y_3$ the numbers of goals scored by a striker then these three only share parameters $\beta_i$ and explanatory variables can be totally different. So why do we choose to study them jointly ?

Comment: $Y_1$, $Y_2$, $Y_3$ must be of the same type, e.g., all being "points you receive when asking a question in this website". They are individual observations of those points received. I can't say why you choose to study them jointly when they are of different types. It must be a mistake of your class.

Comment: @Alex Ok ! I think its more a misunderstanding from my side though. I thought that "explanatory variables are different" meant that they literally represent different things for example $x_{21}$ would have represented years of experience and $x_{31}$ a shot power. But if $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3$ are of the same type then $x_{21}$ and $x_{31}$ represent the same concept but with different numerical quantities. I think I got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, it wouldn’t make sense to have single model explaining completely unrelated things. $(y_i, X_i)$ are all of the same kind. For example $y_i$ is some economic indicator where $i$ is index for different countries and $X_i$ are the independent features for the countries (same for each country). Another example could be where $y_i$ is height of the child and $x_i$ height of the parent, where $i$ is an index for different parent-child pairs, as in the [famous example by Sir Francis Galton](https://zenodo.org/record/1449548).

Loosely speaking, this is what is meant by the assumption that the random variables are [independent and identically distributed](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/213464/35989) that you will see in different places. What it tells is that they are independent and of the same kind.